# How to convert .xls file to .csv file?

Tags: perl, csv, xls

How to convert `.xls` to `.csv` in perl? what is the module for this? Is there any example for this?
what is the best way to convert?

```
use Spreadsheet::ParseExcel;
my $xlsparser = Spreadsheet::ParseExcel->new();
my $xlsbook = $xlsparser->parse('/home/Admin/Downloads/abc.xls');
my $xls = $xlsbook->worksheet(0);
my ( $row_first, $row_last ) = $xls->row_range();
my ( $col_first, $col_last ) = $xls->col_range();
my $csv = '/home/Admin/Downloads/ram.csv';
for my $row ( $row_first .. $row_last ) {        # Step through each row
    for my $col ( $col_first .. $col_last ) {    # Step through each column
        my $cell = $xls->get_cell( $row, $col ); # Get the current cell
        next unless $cell;
        $csv .= $cell->unformatted(); # Get the cell's raw data -- no border 
                                      # colors or anything like that
        if ($col == $col_last) {
            $csv .= "\n"; 
        } else {
            $csv .= ","; 
        }
    }
}
open(my$FH ,'>',"$csv") or die "oops!";

while (my$line = <$xlsbook>){
    print $FH $line;
}
```

oops! at csv.pl line 23.

Comment: some good reference http://www.ehow.com/how_7352636_convert-xls-csv-perl.html http://vinayhacks.blogspot.in/2010/04/converting-xls-to-csv-on-linux.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [converting .xls file to .csv file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21772377/converting-xls-file-to-csv-file)

Answer (score 1):

Use a perl script. Using the Spreadsheet::ParseExcel perl module from CPAN to parse the xls file followed by output as csv should work fine.

[Here is the link](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Spreadsheet-ParseExcel)

[and this link](http://www.unix.com/shell-programming-scripting/222095-python-cleanse-line-strip.html)

Answer (score 1):

You have typos in your code.

```
open(my $FH ,'>',"$csv") or die "oops!";

while (my $line = <$FH>){
    print $FH $line;
}
```

Comment: i'm getting Not a GLOB reference at csv.pl line 26. this error

Comment: fixed the variable name, pls try again.

Comment: I think it is wrong `open(my $FH ,'>',"$csv") or die "oops!";

while (my $line = <$FH>){
 `