# converting .xls file to .csv file?

Tags: perl, csv, xls

My perl script for converting .xls to .csv

```
use Spreadsheet::ParseExcel;
my $xlsparser = Spreadsheet::ParseExcel->new();
my $xlsbook = $xlsparser->parse('/home/Admin/Downloads/abc.xls');
my $xls = $xlsbook->worksheet(0);
my ( $row_first, $row_last ) = $xls->row_range();
my ( $col_first, $col_last ) = $xls->col_range();
my $csv = '/home/Admin/Downloads/ram.csv';
for my $row ( $row_first .. $row_last ) {       # Step through each row
   for my $col ( $col_first .. $col_last ) {    # Step through each column
       my $cell = $xls->get_cell( $row, $col ); # Get the current cell
       next unless $cell;
       $csv .= $cell->unformatted(); # Get the cell's raw data -- no border 
                                     # colors or anything like that
       if ($col == $col_last) {
           $csv .= "\n"; 
       } else {
           $csv .= ","; 
       }
   }
}
open(my$FH ,'>',"$csv") or die "oops!";

while (my$line = <$xlsbook>){
    print $FH $line;
}
```

oops! at csv.pl line 23.

Throwing error. What is the wrong in my code? Please find the error going in my code.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: $csv initially points to the path. Then why are you appending data to the variable. When you are opeining the file at open(my$FH ,'>',"$csv") or die "oops!"; does it contain the name or contents?

Comment: it containing content only

Comment: If this question is identical to [your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21771708/725418) (which it seems to be), you should add new information to that instead of opening a new question. One of your questions might otherwise be put on hold as being a duplicate.

Comment: Then you should have a new variable to hold the file name. Open the file and the print the contents.

Comment: While running above script i'm getting error. Thats why i open new question

Comment: @Ram That error was included in the previous question as well. I should know, I just edited that question in the exact same way. To find out what the real error is, you should include the error variable `$!`, like so: `open(my$FH ,'>',"$csv") or die "Cannot open $csv: $!";`

Comment: can you tell me how to thais

Comment: Don't ask the same question twice! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21771708/how-to-convert-xls-file-to-csv-file Flagged as duplicate

Comment: `$cell->unformatted(); # Get the cell's raw data -- no border colors or anything like that` -- this doesn't have anything to do with border colors.

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo:

```
open(my $FH ,'>',"$csv") or die "oops!";
```

Use strict and warnings and you got warnings during compile time.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
```

You have typos:

```
open(my $FH ,'>',$csv) or die "oops!";

while (my$line = <$FH>){
```

Regards,

Comment: I used `use strict;
use warnings;` but still same error